# InApp Android : Enable various subscriptions

Tags: android, android-activity, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Doing InApp in android. In that how to do InApp to give user a choice for subscription . Eg for 1 week, 1 month etc.. Is that done in the **Developer Console**

```
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_INFINITE_GAS,
            IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_SUBS, RC_REQUEST,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

Also when using this query, how can I get the subscription type

Comment: Try this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial). It'll help you